# Using a property called Id in Razor causes exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some code in Razor, and part of the model has an Id property, as below.

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Data)
{
    var thisId1 = row.Id; // error CS0815: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
    var r = row as HtmlTableRowData;
    var thisId2 = r.Id; // error CS0815: Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
    var x = row.Id.ToString(); //error CS0119: 'NameExtensions.Id(HtmlHelper, string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
}
```

`row` is of type HtmlTableRowData:

```
public class HtmlTableRowData
{
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
    public string OnClick { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; } // Don't use Id as doing so will confuse MVC
    public List<HtmlTableRowCell> Cells { get; set; }
    public HtmlTableRowData()
    {
        Cells = new List<HtmlTableRowCell>();
    }

    public void AddCell(string name, string innerHtml, Dictionary<string, string> attributes = null, bool isIconCell = false)
    {
        Cells.Add(new HtmlTableRowCell(name, innerHtml, attributes: attributes, isIconCell: isIconCell));
    }

    public void AddCells(IEnumerable<HtmlTableRowCell> cells)
    {
        Cells.AddRange(cells);
    }
}
```

As per the comments above, I get the specified exceptions when trying to access the Id property because MVC is referencing the Id extension method instead of my property, even when I explicitly cast `row` to my class `HtmlTableRowData`

I can rename my property to solve the problem, but is there a way of making the above work if the property name is kept as `Id`?

Comment: could you put mode details into the issue? What is your view model and provide sources for `HtmlTableRowData`? Does it work if you use explicit type instead of var?

Comment: Somewhat bafflingly, I came back to it today with a new instance of Visual Studio and restored the `Id` fieldname and it worked as expected.  Yesterday I tried restarting the app and may have reloaded the solution, but possibly didn't close and restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as this looks like it was a transient error/issue with Visual Studio (2022, V17.6.3).

Yesterday when I posted the question, I'd tried restarting the application, and think I tried closing and reopening the solution, but I *didn't* try restarting Visual Studio.

Today I began afresh with a new instance of Visual Studio, restored the original `Id` property name and the problem no longer manifested.